# Assigning a a sequence number to dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, django

I have written a django query like this.

```
stud_record = Student.objects.filter()
```

Thus stud_record is a queryset.

Now what I want to do is, i want to calculate the total num of stud_record, and then divide it by 5.

For ex: I have 20 records in `stud_record`. After dividing by 5 I got 4 each. So now i want to rank the first four students as ran 1, then from 5-8 students as rank 2....16-20 students as rank 5. This rank will be inserted to the same `stud_record` and will be send to the template page.

How can we do it.

Currently I am getting the structure like this

```
[{'name': u'mark', 'roll': 71}, 
 {'name': u'robin', 'roll': 42}, 
 {'name': u'julien', 'roll': 39}]
```

After division and inserting the rank it should look like

```
[[{'name': u'mark', 'roll': 71, 'rank': 1}, 
  {'name': u'robin', 'roll': 42, 'rank': 1},] 
 [{'name': u'julien', 'roll': 39, 'rank': 2}]]
```

Right now I am getting 185 results in my stud_record. After dividing 185/5 i am getting 37 as result. Now i want to give rank 1 to 1-37 students, then rank 2 to 38-75 students... like this

Comment: what should the result be if there are 21 student records?

Comment: 1-5 rank1, 6-10 rank 2....15-21 rank 5

Comment: 1-5:1, 6-10:2...15-21:5, and how do you split up the 11-14 between 3 and 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ranks to your dicts first and then group them using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [{} for _ in range(21)]  # simple testlist

def rank_it(lst,n):
    for index,d in enumerate(lst):
        rank = index/(len(lst)/n)+1
        d['rank'] = rank if rank < n else n

rank_it(lst,5)  #  add ranks
[list(g) for _,g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x['rank'])]  #group by rank
```

*out:*

```
[[{'rank': 1}, {'rank': 1}, {'rank': 1}, {'rank': 1}],
 [{'rank': 2}, {'rank': 2}, {'rank': 2}, {'rank': 2}],
 [{'rank': 3}, {'rank': 3}, {'rank': 3}, {'rank': 3}],
 [{'rank': 4}, {'rank': 4}, {'rank': 4}, {'rank': 4}],
 [{'rank': 5}, {'rank': 5}, {'rank': 5}, {'rank': 5}, {'rank': 5}]]
```

*NB! This solution needs the list to be sorted, if its not, add:
`lst.sort(key=lambda x: x['roll'],reverse=True`)*

Answer (score 0):

Try using Len(stud_record). This will get you the number of student for that queryset. Then play around with division and modulo to get your desired range of student. Sorry I can't give you a definite solution for the laptop I'm currently using is not installed with a Python program. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah i am getting the total count for stud_record. But not getting the logic how to assign the ranks depending upon the division results...;(

Answer (score 0):

You contradict yourself  in the question on what you want. Your example code of what you want has one list of students, each with a rank. But you *say* you want to assign the same rank to all students in a sublist. That's two different things.

For giving an order number for each record in a list do this:

```
for rank, student in enumerate(student_list):
    student['rank'] = rank
```

For giving the same rank to all records in a sublist you can do this:

```
for rank, student_list in enumerate(all_students):
    for student in student_list:
        student['rank'] = rank
```

But this last thing is surely easier, even completely trivial, to do when you are splitting the main list into sub_lists, not afterwards.

Do that for each of the sublists you have created.

Also don't insert it into stud_record, instead add the results to the context. In a class-based view you can do it like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(KlassDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add data to the context:
    stud_record = Student.objects.filter()
    context['stud_ranks'] = calculate_ranks(stud_record)
    return context
```

Now you have the 'stud_ranks' variable available in the template.

Comment: Yeah this is right, but how can i assign first 1-4 students as rank 1, then the next set of students as rank 2 etc..

Comment: I guess this is a method u r invoking here. What should be its definition.

Comment: @sandeep: Also note that your title is completely misleading, if your main question is how to assign ranks. I will change it.

Comment: You have modified the title, that is absolutely fine, no issues. Now i just want to know what should be the definition of calculate_ranks()

Comment: Sorry, but i am bit confused. Right now i am getting 185 results in my stud_record. After dividing 185/5 i am getting 37 as result. Now i want to give rank 1 to 1-37 students, then rank 2 to 38-75 students... like this

Comment: @sandeep: You are very unclear of what you want in the question. I'll update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23197/discussion-between-sandeep-and-lennart-regebro)

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this

```
iter=0
for item in sorted(stud_record, key=lambda x:x['roll']):
    item['rank'] = math.floor(iter / 5) + 1)
    iter+=1
```

You sort your items by 'roll', and assign a 'rank' field that is observing repartition in five bins.

Comment: In the `__future__`, this division will result in a float. So it is better to `math.floor(iter / 5) + 1)`.